# Global view footer not replacing tokens

Tags: views, tokens

I am having a problem with token replacement in a views footer. I added a "Global: Unfiltered text" footer, and checked "Use replacement patterns", and added `[title]`. However, it shows up as the literal string `[title]` on the view, not the title from the first row.

Here's the footer I've created:

[image: replacement pattern in footer]

And here's the view preview:

[image: view preview]

And here's the actual view, where we should see "Sample Article" instead of "[title]". Note that "Sample Article" is the title of an article node, so there is one record showing in this view:

[image: actual view]

I can't tell what I've done wrong. FWIW, I put an export of the view [here](http://pastebin.com/ptqsD47Q).

How can I get the tokens to render properly in my view footer?

Comment: What drupal version are you using 7 or 8?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use the link you provided and noticed that you are not using fields.

> The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.

Now, if you simply select the "Force using fields" in your "Unformatted List" >> "Settings" panel, you will get this to work.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test the sample code I provided : )

Comment: Sure thing, was the best place to start. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the examples provided ... but if a View has no results from the database, then tokens are not replaced.

Comment: "Sample Article" is the title of the one article row. This is showing in the last screenshot.

Comment: If you're up for it, you could import the view export in the link I provided, and see if you get the same behavior.